# Bootstrap Navbar reducing height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar, which is pretty standard, and I want to make it a bit thinner.

So I tried this:

http://www.bootply.com/9VC5N55nJD

But the buttons remain too big. Click the drop down, and you'll see the issue. Is there a way to make the navbar thinner in one place? Or do you need to add css for the navbar and the buttons and what ever else may crop up?

Also, if I say it must be 30px in height - on a mobile, that might be too narrow, so do I need a media query for the different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/B4CgVSZGMt#) is a working fork of your code.

**Bootstrap** by default uses a `padding-top: 15px` and `padding-bottom: 15px` for `.navbar-nav > li > a`. The following CSS will take care of this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

After reducing the screen size (and for mobile devices as you've mentioned) running a **media query** that resets them and kind of makes the `navbar` a bit larger will do the trick. The following is a *hacky* way to do so:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    // enter css for mobile devices here
    .topnav {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .navbar {
        min-height:50px;
        max-height: 50px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does seem to work! It seems a bit of a hack though. It's a shame Bootstrap doesn't make it easier to perform, what I'd think, is a simple request (Thinner nav bar). You code does the trick though. Thanks.

Comment: @Craig I'll let you know if I'm able to find a workaround for this hack. Hope you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css and let me know.

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 40px;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 10px 15px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 6px;
padding: 6px 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That's helpful. The logo text on the right is too low. Do I need css to move that as well?

Comment: Also, in mobile view size, everything has gone out of alignment.

Comment: @ilmk You added way too much CSS in my opinion. This could be done with way less/neater css.

Comment: @James I have used default / the style which he used already. So he can keep the needed css. I know it could be less but it is already neater :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix the `CSS` for the dropdown. Here's the CSS to add to your stylesheet:

```
ul.navbar-nav, ul.navbar-nav li {
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

Changing bootstraps formatting like the navbar has been difficult. They have so many styles that are set, that it's tough to find which one you need to change. Just add the above style to the `css` sheet and you should be gravy.

**Edit**

Also, why not use `height: 40px` if you're just going to set the `min-height` and `max-height` as the same value?

Comment: Add some fiddle. :) So you can see the results of what you are preferring :)

Comment: @HermLuna All the OP has to do is add the CSS to the stylesheet that he/she had in the bootply. It's irrelevant for me to create a full fiddle with such a small addition.

Comment: Ohw. Correction @media(min-width: 768) // Height should be dynamic. :)

Comment: @HermLuna Sure, that would make it better. The solution above is just for the issue the OP had with the dropdown height being greater than the navbar. Not sure why the solution has -2 votes...

Comment: I don't know also. Maybe some trolling downvote. Anyway, great answer.

Comment: @HermLuna Thanks!